# Custom filter from post meta

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, actions

I am trying to create a dropdown filter on the custom post type record listing page.

I have it showing up using a dummy array but can't get it to work with actual data.

```
function wisdom_filter_tracked_plugins() {
  global $typenow;
  global $wp_query;
    if ( $typenow == 'tracked-plugin' ) { // Your custom post type slug
      $plugins = array( 'uk-cookie-consent', 'wp-discussion-board', 'discussion-board-pro' ); // Options for the filter select field
      $current_plugin = '';
      if( isset( $_GET['slug'] ) ) {
        $current_plugin = $_GET['slug']; // Check if option has been selected
      } ?>
      <select name="slug" id="slug">
        <option value="all" <?php selected( 'all', $current_plugin ); ?>><?php _e( 'All', 'wisdom-plugin' ); ?></option>
        <?php foreach( $plugins as $key=>$value ) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" <?php selected( $key, $current_plugin ); ?>><?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
  <?php }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wisdom_filter_tracked_plugins' );
```

The part I need to replace is the $plugins array.

I tried to do something like this:

```
$plugins = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'plugins', 'meta_key' => 'the_date'));
```

And just var_dump() that but it isn't giving me back what I want, I don't even see a date in sight, so I am obviously doing something wrong here.

Comment: I tried get_posts() as well but still no luck. `$plugins = get_posts(array('meta_key' => 'the_date'));` I basically want it to show all the dates that are meta_value for the meta_key 'the_date', for all users, not just the current one or the current row

Comment: I actually found I was better off using a custom SQL query. `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='the_date' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC";` The date was not stored in date format so I have to use STR_TO_DATE